# My Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 is not starting

Tags: rom-flashing, troubleshooting, samsung-galaxy-y

I was installing a custom ROM on my Samsung Galaxy GT-S5360. The installation aborted abruptly and I lost all data from my phone.

Now my phone won't start and is stuck at the Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 logo.

I tried to flash the stock ROM via Odin but it is not detecting my device.

Comment: Bootloop is the problem here. Google it. Is it Galaxy Young?

Answer (score 0):

If Odin is not detecting your device,  it probably means that your device drivers are not installed. Try installing your device drivers first, and then connect with Odin and flash it.

Your problem will be solved.

The other way around is to flash through CWM recovery, if you have it installed on your device. You should have a working ROM zip file.  Place it in SD card and go to CWM recovery and flash it.

Comment: Sir I Have properly install the driver after its not detecting

Comment: Do you have USB drivers installed for the port on which you are connecting your device... because it happens sometimes that if the USB drivers are not installed properly then even if you install your device drivers correctly, you will face connection issues. Try installing USB drivers and recheck...

Comment: @HussainChachuliya OP's question starts with "I was installing a custom ROM on my Samsung Galaxy GT-S5360. The installation aborted abruptly …" – which means there already was an installation running. Which again raises the question: How could that be without the drivers being installed already? Of course provided the first installation was done this way.